# What is the difference between c(1:4) and a <- c(1:4) while passing it to a dataframe to retrieve a set of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a dataframe with 10 columns in it. I want to retrieve the columns `1:4`.

However I am storing the value `1:4` in a variable. Let's call it a. When I try to use `df[,c(a)]` it just gives me the numbers back. However, if I give `df[,c(1:4)]` it gives me the columns. What is the difference? If I use the function `identical` on these two: `identical(c(a),c(1:4))`, it gives me TRUE. What is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is `df` a data.table?  Check `class(df)`.  If not is should work just fine.

Comment: Not reproducible. Post a sample of your `df`. BTW, you don't need `c()` on any of the two cases.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. It was giving me this error :
Error in `[.data.table`(tr, 1, a) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'a' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[,..a] or DT[,a,with=FALSE]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.

So I had to use with=FALSE. This solved it.

Thanks!